# ClickOnce install missing .sdf file after install

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

it seems like a weird issue,
I have a WPF project that I wish to create an installer for -

the project includes a Data\data.sdf folder

[image]

it's correctly compiled and published, I can see the Data folder in the published setup files (check window on the right in image)

however when the installer runs, the Data folder is missing from the final install folder - that's essentially the local database for the app - (check window on the left in image)

[image]

how's it possible that it's present in the installer files and then go missing on install ? - tested on windows 10 on 2 separate machines

I've checked the files in publish settings Application tab and data file is selected as data file and required

on build action, it's set to content and copy if newer

[image]

the database file is internal to the same project and not referenced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, although a bit weird
in the publish options - applications tab, the data file is selected as DataFile(auto) by default - change that to "Include

[image]"

Although I still find it weird, that it would end up all the way in the installer files and then not get copied across